# GIT not working in android studio - no error messages been shown

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am trying to use any of functionality but nothing happens. So here for example I try to checkout the branch. But nothing happens. Studio does not give any error or message. And my branch still stays on `master` and it is the same with any action on git. I am not able to do anything with git from my studio
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my studio for some reason lost path to `git.exe` file. So from settings -> Git -> I just insert git.exe file and it started working fine